# Best practice for typesetting Knuth's up-Arrow notation

Tags: arrows, best-practices

What's the best practice to typeset Knuth's up-Arrow notation?

`\uparrow` and `\upuparrow` are relation symbols (according to `unimath-symbols.pdf`). But in Knuth's up arrow notation, these should be a binary operator. So, how should on treat this difference?

Secondly, should double up arrows be typeset as `\upuparrow` or as `\uparrow\uparrow`, which illustrates the double nature better.

Comment: For the first part, you could define a command using `\mathbin`,as in `\newcommand\kuparrow{\mathbin{\uparrow}}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a command `\mathbin` for creation of binary operators, so something like

```
\newcommand\binuparrow{\mathbin{\uparrow}}
$a\binuparrow b$
```

works.

As to your second questions, tastes differ